# Issue getting credential spec (gMSA) working in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gmsa

I have a gMSA credential spec working with docker run but not with docker-compose. Details for the compose file and the docker run command are below. I'm completely lost as to what I'm missing. I did a lot of googling and I'm not sure what's going on. My primary thoughts is that something with the docker-compose file is off, but I'm not sure.

Docker-compose

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  basic:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
    entrypoint: ping -t localhost
    hostname: server01
    security_opt:
      - credentialspec=file://server01.json
    dns:
      - "192.168.43.2"
    user: "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: "Net"
```

After running `docker-compose up`

```
C:\Users\administrator> docker exec -it b9e2a783ab09 powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Ethernet) 10:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4416:3381:8d1a:122a%43
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.18.42
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
PS C:\> ipconfig /renew

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Ethernet) 10:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4416:3381:8d1a:122a%43
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.198
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
PS C:\> nslookup testdomain.local
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.43.2

Name:    testdomain.local
Addresses:  192.168.43.2
          192.168.52.133

PS C:\> nltest /sc_verify:testdomain.local
I_NetLogonControl failed: Status = 5 0x5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

docker run

```
docker run -it --security-opt "credentialspec=file://server01.json" --user="nt authority\system" --hostname="server01" --network="Net" --dns="192.168.43.2" mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 powershell
```

```
PS C:\> nslookup testdomain.local
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.43.2

Name:    testdomain.local
Addresses:  192.168.43.2
          192.168.52.133

PS C:\> nltest /sc_verify:testdomain.local
Flags: b0 HAS_IP  HAS_TIMESERV
Trusted DC Name \\dc01.testdomain.local
Trusted DC Connection Status Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
Trust Verification Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
The command completed successfully
PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey so I'm leaving this up as a mark of shame.

Notice that I used different users? Turns out I needed to use system and not the network service account. That fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Use double-quoted:

```
security_opt:
  - "credentialspec=file://server01.json"
```